# How do I save a pdf file with editable fields so that when someone else opens it, the fields are not highlighted blue?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, highlighting

I've made a document using Adobe InDesign with check boxes, radio buttons and editable text fields and saved it as an interactive PDF. Looks great in my version of acrobat - problem is, when my client opens it, his version of acrobat has a default setting that highlights all buttons and texts fields in light blue. When he clicks on a radio button and then on another field, the tick in the radio button disappears. If he turns off the highlighting option in Acrobat preferences, all works perfectly. Is there a way to save this PDF so that it defaults itself to viewing with the highlighted fields turned off?

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed, there is a preference setting which highlights fields. This setting can also be controlled with JavaScript. This setting is accessed with the `app.runtimeHighlight` property.

However, as it is a setting the user may have set intentionally, it is not "nice" to just overturn it. Good etiquette is to change it when the document opens, and set it back when the document closes.

So, how to proceed…

Step 1: Create a little document level script:

```
var myHiLight = app.runtimeHighlight ; //save the current value
app.runtimeHighlight = false ; // deactivates the highlighting
```

Step 2: In the `WillClose` Document script add this:

```
app.runtimeHighlight = maHiLight ;
```

And that should do it.

Comment: Genius!! Thank you very much!!